# Change the error message in a SPAN using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the message in a `<span>` using JavaScript/jQuery.

```
<span id="access-code-error" class="rsvp required-fields"> </span>
```

I am using the following code to replace the text which will be added to this `<span>`:

```
$("span:contains('I need <br>this text to be replaced')").text( "hello<br> How r u" );
```

But this isn't working. What do I need to do differently?

Comment: In contains selector "html tags" are not allowed. Html tags breaks selector.
remove "<br>" tag in contains strings and use "html()" method to replace text.

Comment: contains with some html tag inside it will not work. it can be useful only with plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fiddle:

**https://jsfiddle.net/6wcpLpbw/**

Using a html tag inside a `:contains` will not work properly.

`.text()` should be used only with plain text not with html tags inside it.
You should use `.html()` instead of `.text()`.

**Try something like this:**

```
$("span:contains('I need this text to be replaced')").html("hello<br> How r u");
```

> Note: `ID` should be used only once in a page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  jQuery `text()` method like below:

```
$("#access-code-error").text("Your message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have provided the `id` of the `span`, you can use that as shown:

```
$("#access-code-error").text("Your message");
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the error message of your `access-code-error` span, you can do the following:

### JavaScript:

```
var errormsg = document.getElementById("access-code-error");
errormsg.innerHTML = "hello<br> How r u";
```

### jQuery:

1) You can use the `html()` method as shown:

```
$("#access-code-error").html("hello<br/> How r u");
```

2) You can also use the `text()` method in a similar way:

```
$("#access-code-error").text("hello<\br/> How r u");
```

Answer (score 0):

This first `html('')` will remove current text from the `span` and the other one will add the text you want.
:)

```js
$('#access-code-error').html('').html('hello<br> How r u');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="access-code-error" class="rsvp required-fields">This need to be Replaced </span>
```

Comment: using `.html()` twice is redundant once will do the trick since `.html()` gets the html of the element , `.html('')` clears the element much like `.empty()` and `.html('some value')` replaces the content with in the element with the new one much like `.replace()`